# Trying to incorporate JS into shiny

Tags: javascript, shiny

I am trying to incorporate JS into Shiny that is without writing anything to server. Here is the code

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(HTML('<p id="res">Value</p>'),
  tags$script("document.getElementById('res').innerHTMl=x")),
  textInput("x", label = "Text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So basically, whatever we write inside the text box, the "Value" should get changed.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This would do it.

- Try not to put actual content like text inside `tags$head` except meta, link, CSS or script.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    HTML('<p id="res">Value</p>'),
    textInput("x", label = "Text"),
    tags$script("$('#x').on('input', function(){$('#res').text($(this).val());});")
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

pure JS

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    HTML('<p id="res">Value</p>'),
    textInput("x", label = "Text"),
    tags$script(
    "
    document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('input', function(){
        document.getElementById('res').textContent= this.value;
    });
    ")
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks . I see you have put Jquery.  Is it not possible without jquery like the way I had written??? I am new to js and hence starting from scratch

Comment: @manup see edits